# Why does a match against regex $ return 1 when the input string contains a newline?

Tags: regex, perl

Why does the command

```
perl -e "print qq/a\n/ =~ /$/"
```

print `1`?

As far as I know, Perl considers `$` as the position both before `\n` as well as the position at the end of the whole string in multi-line mode, which is the default (no modifier is applied).

Comment: What are you expecting this to return?

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. I think OP's question is, why the return value is `1` and not something else.

Comment: Oh. I have a reopen-hammer?

Comment: Are you expecting it to return 2 instead of 1?

Comment: `/m` (multi-line) is not the default, and the behaviour you described is the behaviour when `/m` isn't used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match operator returns `1` as the true value because the pattern matched. The `print` outputs that value.

The `$` is an anchor, which is a specific sort of zero-width assertion. It matches a condition in the pattern but consumes no text. Since you have nothing else in the pattern, the `/$/` matches any target string including the empty string. It will always return true.

The `$` is the end-of-line anchor, as documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  The `$` allows a vestigial newline at the end, so both of these can match:

```
"a"   =~ /a$/
"a\n" =~ /a$/
```

Without the `/m` regex modifier, the end of the line is the end of the string. But, with that modifier it can match before any newline in the string:

```
"a\n" =~ /a$b/m
```

You might get this behavior even if you don't see it attached to the particular match operator since people can set default match flags:

```
use re '/m'; # applies to all in lexical scope
```

Over-enthusiastic fans of *Perl Best Practices* like to make a trio of pattern changing commands the default (often not auditing every regex it affects):

```
use re '/msx'
```

There's another anchor, the end-of-string anchor `\Z`, that also allows a trailing newline. If you don't want to allow a newline, you can use the lowercase `\z` to mean the absolute end of the string. These are not affected by regex flags.

Answer (score 4):

It prints `1` because there is a match. An ordinary pattern match like `m//` stops after the first match, and returns `1` because that's a true value.

According to that explanation, it doesn't matter if it matches your `"a\n"` after the `a` or after the `\n` character. In either case, there's a match, so it's true, and that's represented by `1`.

You can take a deeper look with [`use re 'debug'`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/re/re.pm#debug-mode).

```
Compiling REx "$"
Final program:
   1: EOL (2)
   2: END (0)
anchored ""$ at 0 minlen 0 
Matching REx "$" against "a%n"
   1 <a> <%n>                |  1:EOL(2)
   1 <a> <%n>                |  2:END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "$"
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the following command works:

```
perl -e "print qq/a\n/ =~ /$/"
```

1. `print` provides a list context,and
2. in list context, `m//` will return "(1)" for success, if there is no parentheses in the pattern, and
3. `$` match the end of the string (or before newline at the end of the string).

Comment: It actually does it in scalar context too. `my $foo = qq/a\n/ =~ /$/; print $foo;` is also `1`.

Comment: @simbabque I guess in this case `perl` using `1` to indicate true value.